# choice_attr option. Advanced configuration

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to add an attribute to each option of the select, whose value is the value of a given property.

I have the following form type class:

```
class ExtraEntityType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * Configures the options for this type.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options.
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $propertyAccessor = new PropertyAccessor();
        $choiceAttr = function ($choice, $key) use (&$propertyAccessor) {
            $value = $propertyAccessor->getValue($choice, 'foo');

            return ['data-extra-value' => $value];
        };

        $resolver
            ->setRequired(['extra_property'])
            ->setAllowedTypes('extra_property', 'string')
            ->setDefault('choice_attr', $choiceAttr);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extra_entity';
    }
}
```

#### THE PROBLEM

I need replace the fixed value `'foo'` by configured `$options['extra_property']`.

**Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem, or if there is some other way to solve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **normalize** your `choice_attr` option like so:

```
$resolver->setNormalizers(array('choice_attr', function($options, $value) use ($propertyAccessor){
    $extraValue = $options['extra_property'];
    return function($choice, $key) use ($extraValue, $propertyAccessor){
         // now you have access the to $options['extra_property'], do what you want with it.
    }
}
```

***Note***: I haven't actually tested this, and it might break, if symfony uses it's own Normalizer for the `choice_attr` option.

Comment: I works with some changes, `setNormalizers` is deprecated in symfony 2.7 and some tags was missing `));`, the logic is right.